# Ошибка в запросе к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Помогите найти ошибку в запросе. Ощущение, что синтаксис подвел.

```
$result_table_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `manager` (code, desc) VALUES (".$manager_item['code'].", ".$manager_item['desc']."); ");
```

Comment: Mysql ругается на этот запрос? Или работает неправильно просто?

Comment: если мне не изменяет память то в `mysql_query` нельзя ставить точку с запятой в конце строки запроса. ну и `desc` ключевое слово необходимо экранировать

Answer (score 3):

```
"INSERT INTO `manager` (`code`, `desc`) VALUES (".$manager_item['code'].", ".$manager_item['desc'].")"
```

desc - ключевое слово

Comment: непонял, можно пояснить что не так ? вряд ли, тут в примере то же как у меня http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: desc - это ключ ассоциативного массива в данном случае, и никак не влияет на сам запрос. Нужно смотреть, что там за данные в массиве

Comment: desc - это ключ массива. Но когда мы пытаемся запихнуть в столбец desc, его имя лучше экранировать

Comment: В данном случае desc никак не влияет на результирующий sql запрос. Это только ключ массива.

Comment: тем не менее, вы его тоже экранировали backquote ;)

Comment: Я заэкранировал не название ключа, а значение, ассоциированное с этим ключем. Читайте код внимательнее

Comment: Так я про него и говорю. А вы все ключ, ключ. Так что это вы читайте внимательнее. ^___^

Comment: Если Вы про desc в качестве заголовка столбца, сразу и нужно было так написать :D Я смотрел на ключ массива :D Вы правы, согласен

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result_table_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `manager` (`code`, `desc`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($manager_item['code'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($manager_item['desc'])."')");
```

Всегда экранируйте данные, которые Вы передаете в запрос.
[mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: странно, то же не прокатило, хотя делаю выборку - выборка идет, а запись нет (

Comment: Что Вас находится в $manager_item? Сделайте var_dump($manager_item), и выложите на пастебин какой нибудь. Хочу посмоттреть.

Mysql Ругается на что нибудь?